# How to define object-level permissions for foreign-key relationships

Tags: django, permissions, django-rest-framework, serialization

I'm having trouble defining object-level permissions for foreign-key relationships in my `ModelViewSet`.  I'm not sure if it's entirely possible what I'm trying to do or if there's a better solution, but any hint in the right direction would be much appreciated.  I've shortened the models and serializers for the sake of brevity.

I have the following models:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team)

class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class FinancialAccount(models.Model):
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then I have the following serializers:

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('name', 'owner')

class FinancialAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = FinancialAccount
        fields = ('name', 'client', 'owner')

    def get_owner(self, obj):
        return client.owner.name
```

Then I'm trying to define a permission that I can use in all of my ModelViewSets.  I'd like it to be somewhat dynamic as I have many more models than the ones above that are related to `Client` or even below `FinancialAccount`.  The permission and viewset are as follows:

```
class IsOwnerTeam(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        teams = request.user.teams.values_list('name', flat=True)
        return obj.owner in teams

class FinancialAccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FinancialAccountSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerTeam, )

    def get_queryset(self):
        teams = self.request.user.teams.all()
        clients = Client.objects.filter(owner__in=teams)
        return FinancialAccount.objects.filter(account__in=accounts)
```

So, right now I'm receiving this error:  `'FinancialAccount' object has no attribute 'owner'`, which makes sense because I don't have an owner field on the `FinancialAccount` object.  But, I thought if I had an owner field in the serializer (and put an owner field in each of the serializers) I could retrieve it that way.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class IsOwnerTeam(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, 'client'):
            owner = obj.client.owner
        else:
            owner = obj.owner
        teams = request.user.teams.values_list('name', flat=True)
        return owner in teams
```